# apigee javaScript fetch do not trigger error 401

Tags: apigee

I'm developing a two apps the use one Collection.
The AdminApp logged users POST/PUT/DELETE in the collection
The ClientApp users (NOT LOGGED IN) execute GET on the Collection.
Everything works but whenever the user let his token expires on the AdminApp the user cannot execute the GET on the ClientApp.

The client executes the code and always return me an 401 error but never trigger the "err" block

```
articles.fetch(
    function(err, data) { // Success
        if (err){
            console.log('SHOULD STEP HERE NO?');
        }else{
            populateCollection();
        }
)
```

Comment: You probably want to set up the guest role to have GET access to that collection then, this way you're not tied to using a token to access anonymously.

Comment: The Guest has the GET role. If I'm either logged out or logged in on the AdminApp, the ClientApp runs. But if the user let the AdminApp expires the token, when he tries to access the ClientApp it uses the expired token to execute the "fetch".

Comment: Can you just prevent the client app from sending the auth header/token?